# How can I install Boot Camp drivers in Windows on an external SSD disk?

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I am going to install Windows 10 on an external SSD disk, so I will need the Boot Camp drivers. How can I install the drivers manually?

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113297/bypassing-boot-camp-to-install-windows-using-a-non-standard-partition-scheme?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Open Bootcamp Assistant (In the Applications -> Utilities folder), then on the opening screen, click the 'Action' menu, then select 'Download Windows Support Software'.  You'll be prompted to select a location to save the downloaded files.  You can then put them onto a USB flash drive, restart into Windows and run the installer.

There are more details on the Apple Support website, [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204923)